# PICASSO GET() METHOD NOT LOADING IMAGE FROM URL IN ANDROID

Tags: android, picasso, loadimage, getmethod

**I used Picasso Get() method to lad a png file from URL. But the app crashes and does nothing.**

**I searched in Internet and community and tried the suggestions and recommendations I found. But alas the problem not solved. Please help me.
This the code.**

```
package com.example.imageapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String MY_URL_STRING ="http://www.geocities.ws/mariyanaatham/2019/may/1.png";
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(MY_URL_STRING)
                .into(iv, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        String msg =e.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg, LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }


}
```

The intention of the code is to display / load 1.png from the URL. If failed toast the error message.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Add the crash error please

Comment: No message, the app closes.

Comment: Can you show the internet permission of the app

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
This line is added in the manifest XML

Comment: You can use the `Glide` I think it will work with that and my question it is why you are  making a `Callback` on that ?

Comment: Thank you for advice. I tried to get the error message but I failed. To avoid closing the app, I put the call back function..